# How to get maximum values of each column in a nested list python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

let say i have a nested list of values

```
values=[[4,2,3],[16,5,0],[3,200,6],[0,10,12]]
```

```py
max(values[x][0]) to get 16
max(values[x][1]) to get 200
max(values[x][2]) to get 12
```

i want output of list
[16,200,12]

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to ask a question according to the [ask] page. We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, this question is a part of big program that me and my friends are doing to show our teacher, if he is satisfied with our project he said he will teach "machine learning" concept to us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip` unpacking the `values` to transpose the matrix and apply `max` to each item in the new iterator:

```
result = [max(x) for x in zip(*values)]
```

Example:

```
>>> values=[[4,2,3],[16,5,0],[3,200,6],[0,10,12]]
>>> result = [max(x) for x in zip(*values)]
>>> result
[16, 200, 12]
```